# How do I build a loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops

How can I build a loop in JavaScript?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**For loops**

```
for (i = startValue; i <= endValue; i++) {
    // Before the loop: i is set to startValue
    // After each iteration of the loop: i++ is executed
    // The loop continues as long as i <= endValue is true
}
```

**For...in loops**

```
for (i in things) {
    // If things is an array, i will usually contain the array keys *not advised*
    // If things is an object, i will contain the member names
    // Either way, access values using: things[i]
}
```

It is bad practice to use `for...in` loops to itterate over arrays. It goes against the [ECMA 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) standard and can cause problems when non-standard attributes or methods are added to the Array object, e.g. by [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/array).
*(Thanks to [Chase Seibert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7679/chase-seibert) for pointing this out in the comments)*

**While loops**

```
while (myCondition) {
    // The loop will continue until myCondition is false
}
```

Comment: You should not use for...in to loop over arrays. This will cause problems with Prototype. See http://www.prototypejs.org/api/array

Comment: The problem with the for-in loops can be avoided if you check with the hasOwnProperty:  if(!things.hasOwnProperty(i)) { continue; }

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a for loop:

We have an array of items **nodes**.

```
for(var i = 0; i< nodes.length; i++){
    var node = nodes[i];
    alert(node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside form the build-in loops (`while() ...`, `do ... while()`, `for() ...`), there is a structure of self calling function, also known as **recursion** to create a loop without the three build-in loop structures.

Consider the following:

```js
// set the initial value
var loopCounter = 3;

// the body of the loop
function loop() {

    // this is only to show something, done in the loop
    document.write(loopCounter + '<br>');

    // decrease the loopCounter, to prevent running forever
    loopCounter--;

    // test loopCounter and if truthy call loop() again 
    loopCounter && loop();
}

// invoke the loop
loop();
```

Needless to say that this structure is often used in combination with a return value, so this is a small example how to deal with value that is not in the first time available, but at the end of the recursion:

```js
function f(n) {
    // return values for 3 to 1
    //       n   -n  ~-n   !~-n   +!~-n   return
    // conv int neg bitnot  not  number 
    //       3   -3   2    false    0    3 * f(2)
    //       2   -2   1    false    0    2 * f(1)
    //       1   -1   0     true    1        1
    // so it takes a positive integer and do some conversion like changed sign, apply
    // bitwise not, do logical not and cast it to number. if this value is then
    // truthy, then return the value. if not, then return the product of the given
    // value and the return value of the call with the decreased number
    return +!~-n || n * f(n - 1);
}

document.write(f(7));
```

Answer (score -1):

A loop in JavaScript looks like this:

```
for (var = startvalue; var <= endvalue; var = var + increment) {
    // code to be executed
}
```