# plain for loop instead of forEach in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, foreach

What's wrong with my code shown below. It doesn't work on IE 8 or lower. 
How can I change it with plain `for` loop instead of `forEach`?

```
var mainItems = [];
[100305, 1003403, 1003511, 1003360, 1002328].forEach(function(id) {
//mainItems.forEach(function(id) {
    mainItems.push(items.filter(function(elem) {
        return elem.id == id;
    })[0])
})
```

Comment: Come on. Try to search at least a little bit

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080/how-do-i-build-a-loop-in-javascript

Comment: Have you looked at any of the basic documentation as far as doing `for` loops in JavaScript? This is a *very* basic question that you're asking.

Comment: Hey men, you guys sooooo smart???? I asked that because I had no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.forEach` is part of the ES5 specification, which [is not supported](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/#) in older browsers. If you plan on using ES5 code, you should look at including [a *shim*](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), which adds support for non-supporting browsers.

As for how to write a `for` loop, [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) can help you there.

Answer (score 1):

you can use simply as

```
 var mainItems = [];

var items = [100305, 1003403, 1003511, 1003360, 1002328];


for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)   
  mainItems.push(items[i]);
```