# Looping over an obj exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm reading [Eloquent Javascript by Marijn Haverbeke](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#4.3) and I'm working on chapter 4's obj to array, and array to obj exercise. The solution to the array to obj is as follow:

```js
var list = {value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null}}};

function listToArray(list){
 var array = [];
 for(var node = list; node; node = node.rest){
  array.push(node.value);
 }
 return array;
}

console.log(listToArray(list));
```

I'm confused on what is happening on the for loop. This is what I do understand:

1. variable node is equal to the list object
2. the length is equal to the node which is the same as the list object
3. and node is equal to the value rest

Can someone break down what is happening in the this for loop in simple terms?

Comment: It's not a dupe! Argh.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ar/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: @Kinduser, the underlying question is around how [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loops work.

Comment: This is basically a self-contained linked-list, where the `rest` property refers to the next element. The for loop runs until node is null, just like you would iterate a linked-list. So it starts on the outside and works its way inward, adding the value to the array using `push()` as it goes along.

Comment: @zzzzBov *underlying* is a keyword.

Comment: @Kinduser [the first answer to the linked question sufficiently answers this question IMO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/52101/497418). Hence the dupehammer.

Comment: @zzzzBov Unnecessary dupe-hammer... OP is not asking how a for loop works, they are asking what it is doing within the context of the surrounding code..

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. @zzzzBov Please, do not abuse your rights to close questions. This one isn't really worth to be closed.

Comment: I'm providing a detailed answer. w8

Comment: @zzzzBov it answers it assuming you're not confused by the usage in this particular question... which is the entire reason for the question. there's no indication the op doesn't understand for loops in general

Comment: @mhodges, "OP is not asking how a for loop works" it's clear to me from reading the question that OP doesn't understand how a `for` loop works, and in gaining that understanding would no longer have the problem in the posted question. But, by all means, reopen if you feel otherwise.

Comment: @zzzzBov The OP clearly explained that they understand how the structure of the `for` loop works via their "1. 2. 3." . I think the OP is more-so having issues with understanding unwrapping nested objects, which is what the code is actually doing. If you want to dupehammer with a question that explains that, feel free

Comment: @mhodges, "The OP clearly explained that they understand how the structure of the for loop works", given that their "1. 2. 3." are incorrect it clearly shows that they *don't* understand how a `for` loop works.

Comment: @zzzzBov You are missing the point. It's not about 'how for loop' works. It's about a **specific** mechanism in this **specific** case. I'm in this business since one year and it's the first time I see such case and solution, actually.

Comment: I understand how for loops work. I'm asking within the context of this code.

Comment: @BehradKhodayar You can add your answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(var node = list; node; node = node.rest)
```

First part (up to first ;) means; initialize node by setting it to list;

Second part means; keep looping until 'node' is null.  This is because the 2nd part is actually an expression, you often see something like `i<list.length` but it doesn't have to involve lengths, it just has to be a boolean, true means keep going and false means stop.  In Javascript you can just put the object variable for the expression, it means the same as `node!=null`

Third part means; after each loop set node equal to the result of node.rest.  Where node.rest is another object to work through.

So the first time it loops, this is what you get

```
node = {value: 1, rest: { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null}}}
```

and it will push `node.value` (which is 1) on to `array`.

Second time it loops you get;

```
node = { value: 2, rest: { value: 3, rest: null}}
```

and it will push `node.value` (which is 2) on to `array`.

And so on until `node.rest` is null.

Comment: Thank you @jimW This makes sense!