# How to create an array of json containing 100 json objects in javascript using for loop with properties id and name

Tags: javascript

How to create an array of json containing 100 json objects in javascript using for loop with properties id and name. Use Math.random() to create random ids. The random number should be between 1-100. E.g. [{id:1,"name":"lorem"},{id:2,"name":"ipsum"}....]

Comment: Post code that you have tried otherwise you will more than likely get no help.

Comment: Actually i am not getting idea where to start from. Please help me.

Comment: Read these: 
[for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080/how-do-i-build-a-loop-in-javascript),

[random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range),

[random string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var out = new Array(100).fill(1).map(function(val, index){
  return {
    "name": "Name number: " + index,
    "id": Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)
  }
});

console.log(out);
```

~or~

```js
var out = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  out.push({
    "name": "Name number: " + i,
    "id": Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)
  });
};

console.log(out);
```