# Performance: Use if in forEach or use filter then forEach the filtered array

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I'm having an item array and I want to perform some tasks on the items which are satisfied some requirements. There are two approaches that can get this done.

First, use `if` clause in `forEach`

```
arr.forEach(item => {
  if (isSatisfied(item)) {
    //...do some tasks
  }
}
```

Second, `filter` the array then use `forEach` with the filtered one.

```
arr.filter(item => isSatisfied(item)).forEach(item => { /* do some tasks */ });
```

The `isSatisfied` will check the item if it meets the condition.

Which one will give me a better performance and why? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I vote for the first

Comment: The first is better but the traditional [old school for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080/how-do-i-build-a-loop-in-javascript) is even faster then `forEach`. Also may be get more reviews here on [code review exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It depends on whether the result of *arr.filter* is reused or not and what percentage of items will be filtered out. Performance may differ greatly between implementations. Use whichever is more semantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one would be more efficient because the second one is looping through some of the items twice.