# Get Google Sheets script to repeat the process until a certain value is reached

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to scripting and not sure how to approach that.

In short - I want the script to copy values from range L3:L118 to N3:N118 until a value of P3 (sum of differences between the 2 ranges) is 0.00. I managed to create a macro for the copying phase, however not sure how to loop it

Here is the code

```
function GetthepriceMK3() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 spreadsheet.getRange('N3:N118').activate();
 spreadsheet.getRange('L3:L118').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Would anyone be able to help with the loop? No idea how to start and the ifs

Comment: What do you mean "sum of differences between 2 ranges"? Unless the cells in a row (say, L10 and N10) are equal? It would be easier if you just show the numbers. What you have and what you want to gain.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. If you haven't done yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. One of the things that you will learn there is that Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as programming language. This programming language has several ways to do loops. One nice resource about loops in JavaScript is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration. If you need further help, please show what you tried and add brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/52080/1595451

Answer (score 0):

#### Collect sum of differences between L and N until sum equals v

```
function GetthepriceMK3() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const l = sh.getRange("L3:L118").getValues();
  const n = sh.getRange("N3:N118").getValues();
  let v = 0;
  let s = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    s += l[i][0] - n[i][0];
    if (s == v) {
      break;//stops the loop
    }
  }
  Logger.log(i);//row is i + 3
  Logger.log(s);
}
```